# How to represent the scatterpoints of a 3D function with GNUPLOT

Tags: gnuplot, scatter3d

I would like to represent in 3D the result of the function f(X,Y,Z) = (X²(Y+Z) + Y²(X-Z) +Z²(-X-Y) -21) with scatter points. Any advice how to do this in GNUPLOT is welcome (in -100 to +100 in each direction).

I am trying to see the "0" place at X Y and Z integer.
The size of the points would be the value returned by the function.

Answer (score 0):

Integer values [-100:100] in 3 dimensions is 8 million points. If you were to draw anything at all for each of those, the resulting display would be be filled at every pixel and not useful as a visualization tool. Coding by size or color at each point will not help.  Now the number of points you are interested in finding may constitute a manageably small subset that can be visualized as 3D scatter plot in gnuplot, but you will have to select those points rather than plotting everything.

The simple approach would be to loop over x, y, z to calculate your function, then if the value is what you want (f(x,y,z)==0?) write out that [x,y,z] triplet to a file.
If the number of points found is reasonable then you can visualize in gnuplot with the commands below.  I use random points between [-1:1] as an example.

```
  unset border
  set xzeroaxis; set yzeroaxis; set zzeroaxis
  set tics nomirror axis
  set xyplane at 0
  splot "zeros" using 1:2:3 with points pt 7 ps 0.4
```

(pointtype 7 is a solid circle, pointsize 0.4 makes them smaller)

[image]

Comment: thanks for the advice. I will have to rethink my topic.

Comment: I see, I am looking at 4D plotting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995610/how-to-make-a-4d-plot-with-matplotlib-using-arbitrary-data. f(X,Y,Z), as density function, should be represented by nothing when negativ, green dot when zero, yellow dot when >0 and <100, light blue dot when >100 and <1000. light grey when <100000, pink when > 100000.  I will further scratch my head. advices are more than welcome. GNUPLOT is still a good startpoint.

Comment: Three was no density function in your original query.  If you can reframe it as a local density function then maybe the development version of gnuplot can do what you want.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484738/heatmap-of-points-in-a-volume/

Comment: thanks. I see a lot of representation of "density" function with matplotlib or gnuplot: bunch of points of non regularly distributed coordinates and same weighting of each point. the "density" I want to represent is defined by points regularly distributed X Y Z (all integers), and at these points, a density value (different to 1; see the f function above) is defined.

Comment: See answer #2. Representing that many points individually is not practical.  You will need to choose some other represenation.

Answer (score 0):

Answer #2: Unless the density function is zero in most places, it fills a solid volume. In order to visualize this volume you will need to select specific points or take slices or something else.  Reasonable options depend on the structure of your function. Gnuplot does now offer several approaches. See this example of using 2D slices taken from the current demo set [voxel.dem](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.3/voxel.html). This approach makes sense for a smooth density function, but probably not for a function where the interesting bits are discrete points rather than regions of space.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]thanks. I will follow later.
i just wrote a script which fullfill a discrete representation
so far enough for me with matplotlib (I was no so familiar with gnuplot).
Also: representing a function "F(X,Y,Z) - A = Result" at (X,Y,Z) all with integers in 3D. Result = 0? point colored black. Else colored.

```
    import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d import proj_transform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import numpy as np

mpl.use('tkagg')

def distance(point, event):
    plt.sca(ax)     # <------------------ introduce this one  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    x2, y2, _ = proj_transform(point[0], point[1], point[2], plt.gca().get_proj())
    x3, y3 = ax.transData.transform((x2, y2))
    return np.sqrt ((x3 - event.x)**2 + (y3 - event.y)**2)

def calcClosestDatapoint(X, event):
    distances = [distance(X[i, 0:3], event) for i in range(Sol)]
    return np.argmin(distances)
#
def annotatePlot(X, index):
    global last_mark, generated_labels
    if activated_labelling:

        x2, y2, _ = proj_transform(X[index, 0], X[index, 1], X[index, 2], ax.get_proj())
        last_mark = plt.annotate(generated_labels[index],
            xy = (x2, y2), xytext = (-20, 20), textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom',
            bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.5', fc = 'yellow', alpha = 0.5),
            arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))

        fig.canvas.draw()
#
def onMouseMotion(event):
    global Coord
    if activated_labelling:
        closestIndex = calcClosestDatapoint(Coord, event)
        last_mark.remove()
        annotatePlot(Coord, closestIndex)       

def show_on(event):
    global activated_labelling, last_mark,pid,mid

    if activated_labelling == False:
        activated_labelling = True
        x2, y2, _ = proj_transform(Coord[0,0], Coord[0,1], Coord[0,2], ax.get_proj())

        last_mark = plt.annotate("3D measurement on " + generated_labels[0],
                    xy = (x2, y2), xytext = (-20, 20), textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom',
        bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.5', fc = 'yellow', alpha = 0.5),
        arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))  
        mid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', onMouseMotion)
#
def show_off(event):
    global activated_labelling
    '''
    deactivate the persistent XYZ position labels at the grafic
    '''
    if activated_labelling:
        activated_labelling = False
        last_mark.remove()
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(mid)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
#ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
activated_labelling = False

Wide = 100
Minimum = -50     
ScanLimit = 3  #  searching between o and 3; 4 and 5 are no solutions
Search = 45

Coord=[]

values=[]

generated_labels = []
#
XMin = 0
XMax = 0
YMin = 0
YMax = 0
ZMin = 0
ZMax = 0

# count the solutions found in the scan area defined above
Sol=0

for i in range(Wide+1):
    for j in range(Wide+1):
        for k in range(Wide+1):

            ########################################################################
            ########################################################################
            ####
            ####                   THIS IS THE POLYNOM TO BE REPRESENTED
            ####
            param_dens = ((i+Minimum)**3)+((j+Minimum)**3)+((k+Minimum)**3) -Search

            if abs(param_dens) <= abs(ScanLimit):
                Coord.append([i+Minimum,j+Minimum,k+Minimum])

                if ScanLimit !=0:
                    values.append([abs(param_dens)])

                labelling = "value {}\nin   X:{}   Y:{}   Z:{}".format(Search+param_dens,i+Minimum,j+Minimum,k+Minimum)    
                generated_labels.append(labelling)
                print(labelling+"\n")

# increase the number indicating the solutions found
                Sol +=1           
# for centering the window          
                if XMin > i+Minimum:
                    XMin = i+Minimum
                if YMin > j+Minimum:
                    YMin = j+Minimum   
                if ZMin > k+Minimum:
                    ZMin = k+Minimum

                if XMax < i+Minimum:
                    XMax = i+Minimum
                if YMax < j+Minimum:
                    YMax = j+Minimum                 
                if ZMax < k+Minimum:
                    ZMax = k+Minimum

print('######################################################')
print('## statistics / move this to a parallel search engine?')
print('## search ')
print("##   total solution %d for searching center %d" % (Sol,Search))    
print("##   from %d to %d" % (Search-ScanLimit,Search+ScanLimit))
print("##   from %d to %d" % (Minimum,Wide+Minimum))      
print('##')      
print('#######################################################')
#
values = np.array(values, dtype='int64')    
Coord = np.array(Coord, dtype='int64')          
#

if ScanLimit !=0:

    cmap = plt.cm.jet  # define the colormap
# extract all colors from the .jet map
    cmaplist = [cmap(i) for i in range(cmap.N)]
# force the first color entry to be black
    cmaplist[0] = (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
# create the new map
    cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom cmap', cmaplist, cmap.N)

# define the bins and normalize
    bounds = np.linspace(0, ScanLimit, ScanLimit+1)
    norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
# create a second axes for the colorbar
    ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.1, 0.03, 0.8])
    cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax2, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
        spacing='proportional', ticks=bounds, boundaries=bounds, format='%1i')

#    
ax.set_xlim3d(XMin-5, XMax+5)
ax.set_ylim3d(YMin-5, YMax+5)
ax.set_zlim3d(ZMin-5, ZMax+5)
#
ax.set_xlabel('X X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Z')

ax.set_aspect(aspect=1)

# extract the scatterplot drawing in a separate function so we ca re-use the code
def draw_scatterplot():
    if ScanLimit !=0:
        ax.scatter3D(Coord[:,0], Coord[:,1], Coord[:,2], s=20, c=values[:,0], cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    else:
        ax.scatter3D(Coord[:,0], Coord[:,1], Coord[:,2], s=20, c='green')

# draw the initial scatterplot
draw_scatterplot()

# create the "on" button, and place it somewhere on the screen
ax_on = plt.axes([0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.05])
button_on = Button(ax_on, 'on')
#
ax_off = plt.axes([0.12, 0.0, 0.1, 0.05])
button_off = Button(ax_off, 'off')
#
#ax_off = plt.axes([0.24, 0.0, 0.1, 0.05])
#button_off = Button(ax_off, 'off')

# link the event handler function to the click event on the button
button_on.on_clicked(show_on)
button_off.on_clicked(show_off)

#fig.colorbar(img)
plt.show()
```